# Separates cart CodeIgniter based store

Tags: codeigniter-3

I am trying to build a cart system, after successfully entering the item to the cart. how can I display items according shop. I was a bit constrained here.

Controllers

```
function to_cart () {
    $data = array(
        array(
            'id'      => '1',
            'qty'     => 1,
            'price'   => 2.400,
            'name'    => 'Asus Eeepc',
            'store'   => 'My_store 1'
        ),
        array(
            'id'      => '2',
            'qty'     => 1,
            'price'   => 1.500,
            'name'    => 'Accer AspireOne',
            'store'   => 'My_store 1'
        ),
        array(
            'id'      => '3',
            'qty'     => 1,
            'price'   => 4.000,
            'name'    => 'Toshiba Satelite',
            'store'   => 'My_store 2'
        ),
        array(
            'id'      => '4',
            'qty'     => 1,
            'price'   => 2.700,
            'name'    => 'Lenova ThinkCare',
            'store'   => 'My_store 1'
        )           
    );

    $this->cart->insert($data);
    redirect($this->agent->referrer()); 
}
```

Views

```
<?php foreach ($this->cart->contents() as $item) { 
        echo '<td>'.$item['no'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$item['name'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$item['price'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$item['qty'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$item['store'].'</td>';
?>
```

Comment: The Cart library is deprecated and will be removed in CodeIgniter 3.2.0; you shouldn't be using it.

Comment: thanks @Narf, whether in CodeIgniter version 3.2.0 will no longer library cart? and can not be used again